# Creating a new categorical variable based on groups and current categorical variable

Tags: r, group-by, grouping, categorical-data

I am trying to create a categorical variable based of of groups and current variables.

My current df has the variables: ID, GroupID, and Drinker. I am trying to create a new variable(GroupDrink) to where if any individual(ID) in a group(GroupID) selects yes for Drinker, then all individuals in that group will have a yes for the new variable(GroupDrink).
Please see the table below for more details.

| ID | GroupID | Drinker | GroupDrink(NewVariable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | 25 | No | Yes |
| 3 | 21 | No | No |
| 4 | 40 | Yes | Yes |
| 5 | 40 | No | Yes |
| 6 | 40 | No | Yes |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
detach(package:plyr) 
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(GroupID)%>% 
mutate(GroupDrink = case_when
any(Drinker == 'Yes') ~ "Yes",
TRUE~ "No"
```

Applying functions to groups seems to work better with the case_when function.
For this to work, the plyr package has to be uninstalled. I had to detach the package for the function to apply correctly to groups.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(GroupID) %>% mutate(GroupDrink = if_else(any(Drinker == 'Yes'), 'Yes','No'))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   GroupID [3]
     ID GroupID Drinker GroupDrink
  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     
1     1      25 Yes     Yes       
2     2      25 No      Yes       
3     3      21 No      No        
4     4      40 Yes     Yes       
5     5      40 No      Yes       
6     6      40 No      Yes
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID GroupID Drinker
  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1     1      25 Yes    
2     2      25 No     
3     3      21 No     
4     4      40 Yes    
5     5      40 No     
6     6      40 No
```

Comment: This seems to provide me with all "yes' for the GroupDrink column...

Comment: @Dflow, how? in the sample data, you can see `GroupID` 3 has `No`.

Comment: when I apply it to a larger dataframe it turns every observation in the GroupDrink column to 'Yes'. Could it be that the group_by function is not working?

Comment: @Dflow are you applying group by on appropriate column ?

Comment: @Dflow, I can't reproduce the issue you have as my code works with the sample data shared.